# Ultimo ID lastInsertId

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert, id

Boa tarde

Pessoal estou tentando buscar o ID que foi inserido pela minha classe porem sem sucesso. Os exemplo que encontrei nenhum funcionou. Se alguem poder ajudar agradeço.

```
public function insert_orcamento($numero, $cod_cliente) {


    $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table (numero, cod_cliente)"
            . "VALUES (:numero, :cod_cliente )";

            $stmt = Conecta::prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':numero', $numero);
   $stmt->bindParam(':cod_cliente', $cod_cliente);


   return $stmt->execute();

   }
```

****CLASSE CONECTA*******
require_once dirname(**DIR**).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php';

class Conecta {

```
private static $instance;
public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        try {
            self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
public static function prepare($sql) {
    return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
}
```

}

Comment: Coloque o código da sua classe `Conecta` também por favor.

Comment: Acabei de colocar ela ali.

Answer (score 0):

Tentou :

```
$stmt->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Se sim qual erro apresenta ?

Comment: Colocando o codigo acima, da o erro abaixo.   Fatal error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\incoterm\classes\IncluirOrcamento.php on line 226

Answer (score 0):

O ultimo ID inserido é salvo na sua instancia do banco de dados.

```
Conecta::getInstance()->lastInsertId();
```